# Two forms submission - one from Menu and one from Body

Tags: struts2

I am using tiles framework in my application. I have two JSP(body.jsp and menu.jsp) files one is for body and one is for Menu(Left hand side menu). Now i want a single submit button in body which will post the both body and menu data to one action class.

Kindly suggest solution for the above said problem

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- Either you make the whole page a big form
- or you could use JavaScript to collect the values from the other form and set them in hidden fields of the other form as soon as they're entered
- or you use JavaScript to construct a URL by collecting the values and don't use forms at all